# Testing Rake task with Rspec with Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test a rake task and it uses an active record in it.

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rake'

load File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'tasks', 'survey.rake')

describe "survey rake tasks" do
  describe "survey:send_report" do
    it "should send a report" do
      Rake::Task['survey:send_report'].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this spec `rspec spec/lib/survey_spec.rb`, I get this error "

```
RuntimeError:
   Don't know how to build task 'environment'
```

How do I load the :enviroment task inside by example spec?

Comment: This guide looks like it may help: http://www.philsergi.com/2009/02/testing-rake-tasks-with-rspec.html

Answer (score 34):

I think you should first load the tasks:

```
require 'rake'
MyRailsApp::Application.load_tasks
```

and then invoke your task:

```
Rake::Task['survey:send_report'].invoke
```

Comment: What is `MyRailsApp`?

Comment: @ZackXu that's the name of your application, you can see that in `config/application.rb`

Comment: You can do `Rails.application.load_tasks`

Answer (score 10):

I suspect the problem is that your `survey:send_report` task depends on `:environment` but you haven't loaded the file that defines the `:environment` task.  That'll be in rails somewhere, and your main `Rakefile` loads it.

So, I think if you change

```
load File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'tasks', 'survey.rake')
```

to

```
load File.join(Rails.root, 'Rakefile')
```

it'll work.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like your take task may need the Rails environment to be loaded. You can stub this out by adding this line to your before(:all) hook:

```
Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your task adding the :enviroment to do it before? In your .rake file you should have something like this:

```
namespace :survey do
# ...

task :send_report => :enviroment do
# ... stuff
end
```

This is because you need to load the full enviroment to do that task. You can check this railcast to get more information http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks